# jQuery DataTable not showing the starting space of its contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, datatables

I have created a `jQuery DataTable` to display the list of employees in a shop. The table structure is like,

```
    <table class="gridTableSummary hover pretty cell-border" id="summarytable" cellspacing="0">
       <thead class="col-header-1" style="height:10px">
          <tr>
             <th>Emp ID</th>
             <th>Employee Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
     <tbody class="text-primary"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Then in script,

```
var meetEmp = $('.gridTableSummary').DataTable({"pageLength": 10, "bFilter": false, "bInfo": false, "bLengthChange": false, "ordering": true, "searching": true});
```

Then assigning values to the table like,

```
 meetEmp.clear().draw();
        for (var i = 0; i <= response.length - 1 ; i++) {
            meetEmp.row.add({
                0: response[i].EmpId,
                1: response[i].EmpName
            }).draw();
        }
```

Where, `response` is a jSon string which contains all the information about employees.

Then, in my database I have some sample employee data which contains some spaces on start of each employee.

Example: `"   u3"` , `"ua3"`, `"        uc2"` and `" ua1"`

But when its showing in `jQuery datatable`, it is removing its spaces from the start. Its looks like,

[image]

How to show the starting spaces in `jquery table`?

Comment: try to replace `space` with `&nbsp`.

Comment: @Raj_King : Thanks. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing `space` with `&nbsp;`.

The working code is,

```
meetEmp.clear().draw();
        for (var i = 0; i <= response.length - 1 ; i++) {
            meetEmp.row.add({
                0: response[i].EmpId.replace(" ", "&nbsp;"),
                1: response[i].EmpName.replace(" ", "&nbsp;")
            }).draw();
        }
```

Now its working fine and getting result like,

[image]

Thanks @Raj_King